# Spring Data JPA - return Future

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-data, future, completable-future

I tried to save my entity asynchronous and return future of the result, but I had following problems:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
//import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

// I must extend Repository because when I extended JpaRepository an argument 
// of save is ambigous when I try save(countryEntity) - compiler shows me 
// save (CountryEntity) in AsyncCountryRepository and save (S) in CrudRepository
public interface AsyncCountryRepository extends Repository<CountryEntity, Long> {

    // I don't know why I cannot return Future<CountryEntity>
    @Async
    <S extends CountryEntity> Future<S> save(CountryEntity countryEntity);

    // I cannot test it - test is below
    @Async
    CompletableFuture<CountryEntity> findByCode(String code);

}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class CountryRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private AsyncCountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Test
    public void findByCodeTest() throws Exception {
        // given
        final CountryEntity countryEntity = new CountryEntity("EN");

        final CountryEntity persisted = entityManager.persist(countryEntity);
        entityManager.flush();

        // when
        final Future<CountryEntity> byCode = countryRepository.findByCode(persisted.getCode());

        // then
        assertThat(byCode.get())
                .isEqualTo(persisted);
    }
```

Test returns Failed and I get `expected:<CountryEntity(id=1, code=EN)> but was:<null>`

How can I implement my repository as asynchronous repository and how to test it?

Which approach has better performance: 
1. return Futures from repository
2. run repository methods as Callable in ExecutorService
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `@Async` the repository code runs in a separate thread within it's own transaction. Since your original transaction isn't committed, it won't see the changes (i.e. the inserted entity) hence the `null` result.

So in order to make it work, you need to commit the first transaction.

Regarding the second question about the performance (Please make separate questions next time): Performance of multithreaded code depends on so many things that really the only useful way to answer it: try it. But I would be surprised if the way how you schedule the execution has more effect on the performance than things like thread pool and connection pool size.